# Java reference to selected values of object to another object?

Tags: java, object, reference

sorry if this question was already asked but I don't even know how to formulate it precisely or just can't find it.

I have class Rule and class Fact

```
public class Rule {
    private Fact first;
    private String operator;
    private Fact second;
    private String operator2;
    private Fact result;
    public boolean fired;
    ...
}


public class Fact {
    private String name;
    private int state;
    private boolean canBeModified;
    ...
}
```

Rules I create based on what I have in file, but there are two ways:
`a && b => c` or `b => a` ( `=>` is not implication here but simply result)

In second case when I lack second fact (`b=>a`) I use `b` again and make it as `b && b => a` and here I want to assign values of `b` to `a` so that `a` is dependent on `b`, and later when `b.state` changes, `a.state` changes exactly the same. Same for canBeModified. Only variables names should be different, constant for each fact. 
How to achieve that?

Comment: Why not then just make A ?

Comment: Question is: why do you want that - as this problem can be solved easily, but there isn't too much sense in that behavior. So maybe you want to tell us how the "real" problem looks like that you are trying to solve.

Comment: facts come in rules. I have rule if b then a (a will have same values as b,)but at the time of creating facts I know only name of those two facts. Values come later and when they come I want to set values of b and values of a will change automatically. Something like this

Comment: If you want to couple (properties of) instances of objects, you should apply the `static` keyword.

Comment: @zx485 that would be too easy. As far as I know `static` makes field 'shared' between ALL instances of this class. I know, I mentioned only a and b, but I have more facts which can't share values. Maybe I'll attach it to main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a new class of state and canBeModified and let a and b share an Object of that class:

```
public class Fact {
    private String name;
    private FactValues values;

    public class FactValues {
        private int state;
        private boolean canBeModified;

        public int getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(int state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public boolean isCanBeModified() {
            return canBeModified;
        }

        public void setCanBeModified(boolean canBeModified) {
            this.canBeModified = canBeModified;
        }
    }

    public Fact(String name, FactValues values) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Fact(String name, int state, boolean canBeModified) {
        super();
        this.name = name;

        this.values = new FactValues();
        values.setState(state);
        values.setCanBeModified(canBeModified);
    }

    public FactValues getValues() {
        return values;
    }


    public void setValues(FactValues values) {
        this.values = values;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return values.getState();
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        values.setState(state);
    }

    public boolean isCanBeModified() {
        return values.isCanBeModified();
    }

    public void setCanBeModified(boolean canBeModified) {
        values.setCanBeModified(canBeModified);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fact b = new Fact("test", 1,true);
        Fact a = new Fact("another test",b.getValues());

        a.setState(5);
        System.out.println(a.getState());
        System.out.println(b.getState());           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `b` to point to `a`.

eg:

```
Fact a = new Fact();
Fact b = a;
```

Now, when `b` changes, `a` also changes, and when `a` changes, `b` also changes.

Comment: aren't you just overwriting class b with class a ?

Comment: This doesn't satisfy OP's requirement that b has a different name.

Comment: @SarkoutMahmoud First of all, they are not classes. Secondly, No. They both just point to the same object.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek `b` has a different name - `b`. Does it not?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi it has a different variable name, but certainly won't have a different value for OP's field 'private String name' which I'm pretty sure is what the OP means.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek Oh that `name`. I thought it was object name. Let me think about it.

Comment: I did that already and b becomes a entirely. I want b to has its name 'b' but to inherit a's values from other fields